# Angular 7 lazy loading with child routes loading the first route always

Tags: routes, lazy-loading, angular7

I have my lazy loaded child routes defined in the module like below... Noticing that the first child (1004D) is being loaded no matter which route I navigate to. Has anyone come across this ??

```
  const reviewRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: ''
  , component: ReviewComponent
  , children: [
    { path: ':1004D', pathMatch: 'full', loadChildren: 'src/app/components/forms/1004D/form-1004d.module#Form1004DModule'},
    { path: ':1004P', pathMatch: 'full', loadChildren: 'src/app/components/forms/1004P/form-1004p.module#Form1004PModule'},
    { path: ':1004C', pathMatch: 'full', loadChildren: 'src/app/components/forms/1004C/form-1004c.module#Form1004CModule'},        
    { path: ':1004',  pathMatch: 'full', loadChildren: 'src/app/components/forms/1004/form-1004.module#Form1004Module'},        
  ]
}
```

];